# A proof involving the falling factorial and the diffrence operator

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I am reading up on combinatorics for an under graduate summer internship in mathematics. But I am in Computer Science. The book that I am using is "Combinatorics and Graph Theory" by John Harris and folks. There's an exercise that is stumping me, and maybe you guys can **point** me in the right direction. Here goes,

**Problem 14.**
Let $\triangle$ be the difference operator: $$\triangle(f(x)) = f(x+1) - f(x).$$
Show that, $$\triangle(x^\underline{n}) = nx^\underline{n-1},$$
and use this to prove, $$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} k^\underline{n}= \frac{m^\underline{n+1}}{n+1}.$$

Now I know that the falling factorial is defined as, $$x^\underline{k} = x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-k+1).$$

Also, I know that this function returns to us the amount of k-element ordered lists from a collection of n different objects. 
I have gotten up to here so far,
$$\triangle(x^\underline{n}) = (x+1)^\underline{n} - x^\underline{n}$$
$$=(x+1)x(x-1)(x-2)...[(x+1) - (n-1)] - x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n+1)$$
rearranging that,
$$=x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n+1)(x-n+2)(x+1) - x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n+1)$$
$$=x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n+1)[(x-n+2)(x+1)-1]$$
$$=x^\underline{n}[(x-n+2)(x+1) - 1].$$
And this guys is where I get lost, because I am tempted to manipulate the above product using the laws of exponents...but to my understanding, $x^\underline{n}$ isn't a power of x (or is it?). I am confused.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake when taking $x(x-1)\dots(x-k+1)$ as a common factor, when in fact there is no $(x-k+1)$ in $(x+1)^{\underline {n}}$:
$$(x+1)^{\underline{n}} - x^{\underline n} = (x+1)\color{blue}{x(x-1)\dots(x-n+2)} \color{black}{-} \color{blue}{x(x-1)\dots(x-n+2)}\color{black}{(x-n+1)}$$
Then we take the common factor:
$$x^{\underline{n-1}} ((x+1) - (x-n+1)) = n x^{\underline{n-1}}$$

Comment: Thank you, I will work on it to understand the reasoning behind this, but you mean to say that $(x+1)^\underline{n} = x^\underline{n+1}$ ? I think I should work on understanding what $x^\underline{n+1}$ and $x^\underline{n-1}$ actually implicate. Thanks!!!

Comment: Oops, typo. :) I fixed it now.

Comment: ahh I see, I'm still having some trouble understanding the concept compared to a normal factorial. But thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: If you'd like, you can express $x^{\underline n}$ as $\frac{x!}{(x-n)!}$.

Comment: So $x^\underline{n} = x^\underline{n-1}[x - (n-1)]$ and $x^\underline{n+1} = x^\underline{n}(x-n)$ would be correct? Following the logic from your answer...

Comment: I've actually just looked it up on https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Properties_of_Falling_Factorial, well I feel dumb now :D